# Access Linked Tables and Their Network Connections

Tags: ms-access, odbc, network

I need to know some simplistic details about how Microsoft Access' linked tables work. I think I know the answer, and this question is more about asking for a confirmation than anything else. A pointer to documentation would be appreciated, as well.

I am testing an Access ancillary application that pulls its data from a crime statistics Informix IDS database. The Access database contains several linked tables to the Informix database, and, using a multi-table query, updates a native Access table with information.

I am assuming if the network link to the Informix database breaks even for an instant, the linked tables' links also break, and the application must be reloaded. Is that assumption correct? I saw this happen when I let the application run overnight. The links were broken, and I believe the network link burped overnight.

The reason I'm asking this, is I have to build in a re-load mechanism into the Access form, so that the user does not have to close the application and re-open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Access form would need to delete the linked tables, and recreate them in order to continue to have access to the remote table.

An interruption of the network connection would certainly cause the symptoms you report.  Having said that, you likely shouldn't be having network issues.  I'd try to find the cause of the issue, as well as building in the ability to deal with the problem in Access.